# Openlayers 3 - Measure delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers, openlayers-3

me again. I stumbled once again on some rather strange behavior. Using ol3 geometry methods I wanted to calculate area using existing [OL3 measure](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html) example. I adjusted a bit mentioned example to use buttons instead of drop-down list.

Long story short: When I click on **area** button I want to erase all previous geometry, remove interaction and remove any existing tooltip from the map. I did managed to remove interaction and geometry but I simply can't remove that pesky tooltip.

I did try removing created div element using code below, but nothing worked.

```
$( ".tooltip tooltip-measure" ).remove();

$("#measure_id").remove();

if (measureTooltipElement) {
         measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
     }
```

Live example is visible on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Svinjica/r67mpa7b/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did find answer and this time my persistence was fruitful. I wanted to delete question because it was relatively *fresh* but I've changed my mind and updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Svinjica/r67mpa7b/) instead :)

Problem was with wrong jQuery selector.

```
$('#measure_id, tooltip tooltip-static').remove();
```

Hope it helps someone :)